# Passing a value obtained in asynchronous function to index.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, argument-passing

I am currently developing one of my first web applications in which a user can select a stock and get stock data in real time using AJAX.

I currently have set it up so a user can select a stock and get information from the database (see demo at 3weekwebsites.com), however now I am trying to construct a chart in the same method which is proving to be significantly more difficult. This is because before I could just display the results using javascript, however now the code I need to make the chart is in my index.html and as far as I am aware, you cannot pass around return values from asynchronous functions.

**HTML**

```
getStock("aapl");

<script>
var chartData = [];
        function createStockChart() {
            ...
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;     
            chart.write('chartdiv');
        }

</script>  
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var stock;

function getStock(str)
    {   
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // Create the object for browsers
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            // if server is ready with the response
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
            {
                // if everything is Ok on browser
                if(xmlhttp.status==200) 
                {    
                    stock = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
                    alert("Can I pass this value along somehow:" + stock);
                }
            }
        }
        //send the selected option id to the php page 
        xmlhttp.open("GET","query.php?symbol="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

As you can see, I would like to pass around the value obtained in my javascript file (variable "stock") so that I can set my chart data in index.html or eventually in another javascript file. I tried making a callback function to move the variable, however I couldn't seem to get this to work since the callback function is asynchronous as well. Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the jQuery tag?

Comment: Sorry I am retarded and I thought there was jQuery in there somewhere... >.< My apologies, new to web development.

Comment: Don't worry for that and welcome on SO! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you can change the function in JS file to take a callback function as argument...

```
function getStock(str, callback){
     //make request and if status 200 makea call to callback function
     if(xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {    
                stock = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
                alert("Can I pass this value along somehow:" + stock);
                callback(stock);
            }
}
```

and in HTML file, pass the callback function...

```
getStock("aapl", createStockChart);
<script>
   var chartData = [];
    function createStockChart(stockVal) {
        ...
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;     
        chart.write('chartdiv');
        //use stockVal
    }

</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I also realized that I can just move the javascript code in my index.html over to the actual javascript file... Then I can just write - success: createStockChart(); so that the function executes once the php script finishes. Thanks for your help, I will go investigate callback functions further :)